# how to implement session tracking for jsp pages

Tags: java, session, jsp, servlets, tracking

I have using jsp technology in my project.I want to do session tracking
in my login form.
After logout when i press back button it should be show
session is expired.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do it manually. The servletcontainer will do it for you. You can access the tracked session by [`HttpServletRequest#getSession()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29). All you need to do is to put the logged-in user as a session attribute.

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
```

Let the rest of your code intercept on that. You usually use a `Filter` for this.

```
if (request.getSession().getAttribute("user") == null) {
    // Not logged in. Redirect to login page.
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
} else {
    // Logged in. Just continue request.
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

When you invoke the logout, just remove the user from the session.

```
request.getSession().removeAttribute("user");
```

The servletcontainer will manage the session expiration as well. When it expires, then the `HttpSession` will simply be trashed, including all of its attribtues.

As to the back button question, just instruct the client to not cache the response so that it's forced to fire a brand new request which would then be passed through the `Filter`. This client instruction needs to happen by setting the response headers accordingly. That could be done in a `Filter` as well.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, session creation and destruction:

Use [HttpSessionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html).

Implement `sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se)` with an output telling you that a session has been created.

Implement `sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)` with an output telling you that a session has been destroyed. That is, a user has logged off, or user's session has expired.

Now, the middle part. Use a [filter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html), with a corresponding `web.xml` entry of `*.jsp` for that filter. Inside of your filter, use `doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)`. Cast `ServletRequest` to `HttpServletRequest`. Using that request you'll have many methods that you can use for session tracking. User's credentials, visiting URL, basically everything that could be of interest.